How to solve object not found error in php project?
First, I need to clarify, I am not a php expert. I only try to set it up as a general test.
I cloned following code:
https://github.com/HAWK-Digital-Environments/HAWKI
I downloaded XAMPP and put the code into the XAMPP htdocs folder.

I started the XAMPP server.

If I try to open the project locally with the following link, it redirects to the login page as defined in the index.php. But I receive the error that the object was not found:
http://localhost/hawki

Translation:

The requested URL could not be found on the server. If you have entered the URL manually, please check the spelling and try again.

If you think this is a malfunction of the server, please inform the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1

If I enter the following link, I receive the same error:
http://localhost/hawki/login

How to I solve the problem and get it running?
Normally, it should work like this page:
https://ai.hawk.de/login.php

Can you translate the error message? It is strange that you'd have a 404 and a PHP error. Can you also please add relevant code, if a PHP script is giving the 404 error (looks like apache error page).

I added the translation. It seems that this error page is caused by apache. I cannot find related code. It seems that it cannot show the redirected code of the index.php

What url does it try to redirect to, precisely? We can't see that from your screenshot

please try enter http://localhost/hawki/public/login

@Yui-Yukino surely that would need .php on the end of the url?

It looks like you didn't set up your host for apache properly You can move content of hawki folder one level up directly into the folder htdocs that could work

@ADyson as Alex mentioned, I put it directly into the htdocs folder. Nevertheless, I receive the same error. The redirection is from localhost/ to localhost/login. I do not have a login.php in the htdocs directly. But as far as I think the navigation should work nevertheless, because of the php code.

@Alex did it. But I receive the same error

Do you have an .htaccess files that does rewrites?

@user3783243 I have a .htaccess file in the private folder (Order allow,deny; Deny from all)


The root folder also has a .htaccess file 2. As stated by others, please move all the files / sub-folders into htdocs (do not put the files / sub-folders into the hawki folder)


@KenLee Thanks, it was a missing .htaccess in the root folder

The .htaccess file of the root was not copied during cloning the project from GitHub.
